# How to save the number of clicks of a button?

Tags: java, android

Basically the user installs the app, enters for the first time and clicks the button [e.g.] 37 times -> now this number has to be saved as a new record because 37 is bigger than 0. The second time the user clicks and he makes [e.g.] 88 clicks. Now I want to save 88 and make possible to see it whenever you want by putting it in a PopupDialog. Where do I start?

That's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView txtCount, textViewTimer;
private Button btnCount;
int count = 0;
boolean[] timerProcessing = { false };
boolean[] timerStarts = { false };
private MyCount timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView digital= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btnRestart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btnRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_record);
    textViewTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    timer = new MyCount(10000, 1);

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // start timer once when button first click
            if (!timerStarts[0]) {
                timer.start();
                timerStarts[0] = true;
                timerProcessing[0] = true;
            }

            if (timerProcessing[0]) {
                count++;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        }
    });
    btnRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timerStarts[0] = false;
            timerProcessing[0] = true;
            count = 0;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            timer.cancel();
            textViewTimer.setText("10:000");

            if (btnCount.isPressed()) {
                timer.start();

            }

        }

    });
    btnRestart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vb.vibrate(1);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
        timerProcessing[0] = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + ":"
                + millisUntilFinished % 1000);

    }

}
```

I have no idea how to do this, may you help me please?

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Which part of the code are you talking about?  What are you trying to save and how are you trying to do it.  Seems like you could just store # of clicks in some class level variable, unless you want to save this count across state changes like on a orientation change or pause/resume, in which case yuou'll need to save the variable in a bundle or some other persistance mechanism like sharedPreferences.

Comment: **txtCount** displays the number of clicks you do with the button and I would like to save this number everytime the user scores higher than the previus times

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use the the class instance variable count to save the count you are interested in.
Because your activity is disposed and recreated, you need to save this variable in onSaveInstanceState lifecycle event handler and restore it in onCreate.  It would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt("SavedCount", count);

    //Cll the superclass 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Restore the variable in the onCreate method as follows:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first
     // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
     // Restore value of members from saved state
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt("SavedCount");
     } else {
       count = 0;// Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
     }
     //...rest of oncreate method
  }
```

Comment: So with this I am able to save somewhere the number of clicks a user do?

Comment: Yes, if you've defined count to be updated in the onClick event you are interested in, these two methods will save the value you've ascribed for the variable between lifecycle events (like when orientation changes, or when the user returns to the home screen etc.)

Comment: But I don't see how I can save a record permanently until another is done. I don't know how to explain it...
So: the user install the app and click the button [e.g.] 37 times > now this number has to be saved as a new record because 37 is bigger than 0. The second time the user clicks the button, he makes [e.g.] 88 clicks. Now I want to save 88 and make possible to see it whenever you want by putting it in a PopupDialog.